# How should I format my .dat file so that a 3D vector plot can be made?

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, field, gnuplot

I'm working this programming task for college where we have to write a `c++` program that calculates the magnetic field vector for certain coils in 3D space.

I've managed to write this program and I think I've got it working pretty well.

I want to add in a special thinh though (it's my exam paper, so it has to be extra good!): I wan't to plot the vectors out.

I'm used to calling `gnuplot` from `c++` (via piping) and this is what I usually do:

1. create an output stream that writes the data to a `.dat` file
2. open a gnuplot pipe
3. make gnuplot plot all the contents of the `.dat`

Since my data has always been 2D, `x`and `y` plots, I'm quite lost here. My question is:

1. How to format the `.dat` file (e.g. do I use braces to group vector components?)
2. what is the actual gnuplot command to plot a 3D vector field?

It'd be easy if I could format the `.dat` file like this:

```
# Px    Py    Pz    Bx    By    Bz
  1     0     2     0.7   0.5   0.25 #<= example data line
  ... more data ...
```

when the magnetic field vector in the point `P=(1,0,2)`equals a vector `B=(0.7,0.5,0.25)`. This would be easy to program, the real question is: will this do ? and how to I plot it in gnuplot. (wow, I've asked the same question 3 times I guess).

---

### *Piping* to gnuplot

Ok, since someone asked me to describe how I *pipe* (don't know if it's the right term thought) stuff to `gnuplot`. Here it is:

1. First open up a pipe and call it `pipe`:

   ```
   FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist 2>/dev/null", "w");
   ```
2. Tell `gnuplot` what to do through the pipe:

   ```
   fprintf(pipe, "set term x11 enhanced \n");
   fprintf(pipe, "plot x^2 ti 'x^2' with lines\n");
   ```

   notice the `\n`which is absolutely necessary. It is what executes the command.
3. close the pipe:

   ```
   pclose(pipe);
   ```

The necessary library is called `<fstream>` I believe.

Comment: I'm very interested in the "pipe" way you use to call gnuplot in 2D. Can you give a brief piece of code? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made this simple example to show you how to draw a vector field. The output would be something like this pic:

[image]

The data example I used to plot this was:

```
# Px    Py    Pz    Bx    By    Bz
  0     0     0     0.8   0.8   0.45
  0     0     1     0.5   0.7   0.35
  0     0     2     0.7   0.5   0.25
  0     1     0     0.65   0.65   0.50
  0     1     1     0.6   0.6   0.3
  0     1     2     0.45   0.45   0.20
  1     0     0     0.5   0.7   0.35
  1     0     1     0.75   0.75   0.4
  1     0     2     0.85   0.85   0.25
  1     1     0     0.90   0.85   0.23
  1     1     1     0.95   0.86   0.20
  1     1     2     0.98   0.88   0.13
  2     0     0     0.73   0.83   0.43
  2     0     1     0.53   0.73   0.33
  2     0     2     0.73   0.53   0.23
  2     1     0     0.68   0.68   0.52
  2     1     1     0.63   0.57   0.23
  2     1     2     0.48   0.42   0.22
```

The command to plot it is:

```
gnuplot> splot "./data3d.dat" with vectors
```

Now you should read the section 44, page 53 of the [official manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html) (and here the [pdf](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf)). You may find [this site](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/style-e.html#vector) also very useful.

Edited:

This command doesn't fit into your description: mapping `from (x,y,z) to (t,u,v)`. It actually does this mapping: `from (X,Y,Z) to (X+dX,Y+dY,Z+dZ)`.

Cheers,
Beco

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much for the pipe code. I'm sure going to use it somewhere. :)