# Making data files with gnuplot

Tags: vector, 3d, gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot. I am trying to plot 3d vector fields. I know that I have to create a data file that has six columns representing x, y, z, deltax,deltay, deltaz.

I wondering if it is possible to define a function f(x,y,z) and have gnuplot create the data file I desire in order to plot the vectors. 
If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the special file name `++` to create a 2d grid on which you can define you vector field:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
set samples 100
set isosamples 100

vx(x,y,z) =  ...
vy(x,y,z) = ...
vz(x,y,z) = ...
z(x,y) = ...

splot '++' using 1:2:(z($1,$2)):(vx($1,$2,z($1,$2))):(vy($1,$2,z($1,$2))):(vz($1,$2,z($1,$2))) with vectors
```

This plots a vector field `(vx,vy,vz)` on the surface `z(x,y)`. Gnuplot cannot generate a 3d grid.

You could try to simulate such a real 3d vector field with a loop:

```
z(i) = -10 + i*(20.0/99.0)
splot for [i=1:100] '++' using 1:2:(z(i)):(vx($1,$2,z(i))):(vy($1,$2,z(i))):(vz($1,$2,z(i))) with vectors lt 1
```

As example considert the following script for a central force:

```
lim = 2
N = 6

set xrange [-lim:lim]
set yrange [-lim:lim]
set zrange [-lim:lim]
set samples N
set isosamples N

sc= 0.3
r(x,y,z) = sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
gx(x,y,z) = sc/(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) * x/r(x,y,z)
gy(x,y,z) = sc/(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) * y/r(x,y,z)
gz(x,y,z) = sc/(x**2 + y**2 + z**2) * z/r(x,y,z)

z(i) = -lim + 2*i*lim/(N - 1.0)

unset key
set xyplane 0
splot for [i=1:N] '++' using 1:2:(z(i)):(gx($1,$2,z(i))):(gy($1,$2,z(i))):(gz($1,$2,z(i))) with vectors lt 1
```

with the output

[image]

Comment: Okay I see thanks! But I don't know I am trying to make a 3D grid.

Comment: Okay, I see; thanks! However, I don't know if I am trying to make a 3D grid. I want to define a function f(x,y,z) that will output a data file with six columns (x,y,z,Vx,Vy,Vz) where (x,y,z) represent 3D input points and (Vx,Vy,Vz) represent 3D vector coordinates. I've seen that it is possible to do this; all I need is the right data file; after that I should be able to use "splot <datafile> 1:2:3:4:5:6 with vectors" to plot the vector field. I hope you understand what I mean. (I tried to edit my comment but it didn't work.)

Comment: Here is a link to basically what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666443/how-should-i-format-my-dat-file-so-that-a-3d-vector-plot-can-be-made. I want to define a function that can output a data file with 6 columns; then I should be able to use "splot" with relative ease.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you want, but gnuplot doesn't support 3D grids, you cannot plot a function of three variables `f(x,y,z)`, but only `f(x,y)`. In the case of vector fields you can get the third dimension via the `for` looping. I updated my answer to show a concrete example for the 3D vector field of a central force. That is the gnuplot-way of plotting this. If you want to generate a data file first, and plot this with gnuplot, that you should use an external script/program (e.g. python) to create this data file.

Comment: Okay, I see. You've really helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here an answer that would apply to a 3d surface plot. I'm sure this can be expanded to work for a vector field as well - a matter of writing the function which is outside my comfort zone.

You would plot your function to a table rather than a graphic output and then plot the graph using the table you just have produced (and could inspect, edit etc. before). Sample:

```
# output to a file with the data
set table "so.dat"

# plot your function
splot [-2:2][-2:2] exp(-(x**2 + y**2))*cos(x/4)*sin(y)*cos(2*(x**2+y**2))

# switch the graphic screen on again and plot from your file
unset table
unset ztics                       # avoiding cluttered ztics
splot "so.dat" u 1:2:3 w l
```

yields

[image]

Sample taken from Philipp K. Janert, Gnuplot In Action

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was trying to do. Do you know where or who would be able to assist me in defining vector fields?

Comment: Upvoting or marking as accepted would be nice if it was what you were looking for. For defining vector fields, maybe you better ask for help on [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: upvote: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up, accept: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer